# Is There A Performance Gain Of Ajax Calls To Separate Server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, performance

I have PHP application that makes it ajax calls to subdomain.

```
www.example.com
api.example.com
apix.example.com
```

I use `api.example.com` for short ajax request while `apix.example.com` is used for longer operations. The idea behind that was not to hit the browser's waiting queue for max ajax calls per domain.

Right now all the ajax calls are on the same server that process the request through PHP. I've begun to notice as of late the request take longer to return, and it seems the server is the web server bottleneck and not the database.

So my question would there be a performance gain by having all ajax request performed on a different server? Are there other methods for improving the speed of ajax request?

Comment: if your server can't keep up with the requests, and the other calls would be made to different servers, then it's reasonable to assume you could avoid the backup and thus speed your execution.

Comment: what is the bottleneck on the web server? its response? time to connect? time to process the request? are your dns lookups taking a long time?  A new server may not speed anything up unless you know where the bottleneck is.  Can you give us more insight?

Comment: The bottleneck seems in the time spent waiting for an initial response. Receiving, connecting, etc is very quick. I'm guessing that would be response time.

Comment: What server are you running? Apache, node, nginx, webrick?

Comment: Apache on Centos installed through yum